# How can I combine a pattern texture with a UV map in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, uv-image-editor, procedural

I have some limited knowledge of creating materials w/ Blender Cycles, but this issue is a bit out of my level of knowledge.

What I'd like to do is take a repeating texture--a "lizard/snake skin" pattern, and apply it to a mesh. I'd then like to apply a UV map on top of it while preserving the effect of the snakeskin. The end product should look like a colored snakeskin, so to speak. Ideally, I'd like the snake skin to have a "bump map" feel, or to simulate depth to a certain extent.

The image below resembles what I'm going for.

[image]